# Hi I have written a following mysql query but its taking too much of my cpu.how can I optimizie it

Tags: mysql

```
set @points := -1;
set @c := 1;
set @num := 0;
SELECT `player_id`,`name`,`firebase_token`,`highscore`,`fb_pic_url`,`profile_pic`
          , @num := if(@points = `highscore`, @num, @num + @c) as rank
          , @c := if(@points = `highscore`, @c+1, 1) as dummy
          , @points := `highscore` as dummy2
        FROM 
        (SELECT  `Match_History`.`player_id`,`players`.`name`,`players`.`firebase_token`,`players`.`profile_pic`,`players`.`fb_pic_url`,`Match_History`.`highscore`
            FROM `Match_History`,`players`
            WHERE (`Match_History`.`player_id`,`Match_History`.`highscore`) IN 
            ( 
              SELECT `player_id`, MAX(`highscore`)
              FROM `Match_History`
              WHERE `contest_id`=128
              GROUP BY `player_id`
            ) 
            AND `Match_History`.`player_id`=`players`.`id`
                GROUP BY `players`.`id`
            ORDER BY `Match_History`.`highscore` DESC ,`Match_History`.`timestamp`
        ) t 
        ORDER BY `highscore` desc, `player_id` asc;
```

I am using above mysql query to create leaderboard from a tables mentioned as below:

**Match_History**:

`id` int(11) NOT NULL,

`player_id` int(11) NOT NULL,

`contest_id` int(11) NOT NULL,

`highscore` int(11) NOT NULL,

`timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

**Players:**

`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,

`profile_pic` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,

`fb_pic_url` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,

`firebase_token` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,

`timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

above query is taking too much of CPU and I want to optimise it.
i am trying very hard but unable to find a right way to get same result with more optimise way.
can some one help me with it?

Comment: Couldn't you use joins?

Comment: Use EXPLAIN to see where the potential problems with the query might be.

Comment: It takes too many resources in DB interface or when brought to PHP?

Comment: What is EXPLAIN
and I am sorry I am not very good at mysql but I am trying to Improve.
Can some one help me with how can I use JOINs here.
according to my research using joins can optimise it

Comment: Its taking while to execute in db only

Comment: This query looks overly ornate and at a glance seems to be the wrong way to solve the problem. Try to think of a *relational* approach, not a *procedural* one.

Comment: OK I will try to look into it
my main problem is I need to calculate ranks of users while selecting. 
and there could be some players sharing same rank.
lets say there are 3 player sharing rank 2 since they have same score
then next rant should be 5 and rank 3 and 4 should be skipped.
I tried very hard but could not optimise it.

Comment: The PHP tag should be removed in that case because that is not part of your bottle neck. For `explain` you put that in front of your query and it will give a list of what it is doing. For example `explain select ... from ...`

Comment: when i put EXPLAIN in front of my select it mysql only returns
# Rows: 4

Comment: Yes, those rows have the information in them... or you are just getting back `Rows: 4 `?

Comment: just getting back rows :4 no real rows nothing

Comment: What interface are you executing your query through?

Comment: I am using PhpMyAdmin

Comment: That is strange. I've never seen it return that before. Could you try it from your DB directly please?

Comment: I dont know how to do that 
i am on aws server how can i run mysql there?

Comment: `mysql -uroot -p` then press enter when prompted for the password, if there is no password.

Comment: i think joins can help me in this case can you help me to rewrite this query using joins

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a first crack at using joins:

```
SELECT  `Match_History`.`player_id`,`players`.`name`,`players`.`firebase_token`,`players`.`profile_pic`,`players`.`fb_pic_url`,`Match_History`.`highscore`
FROM `Match_History` MH 
JOIN `players` P on MH.player_id = P.id
JOIN  ( 
  SELECT `player_id`, MAX(`highscore`)
  FROM `Match_History`
  WHERE `contest_id`=128
  GROUP BY `player_id`
) HS on HS.player_id = MH.player_id and HS.highscore = MH.highscore
GROUP BY `players`.`id`
ORDER BY `Match_History`.`highscore` DESC ,`Match_History`.`timestamp`
```

Make sure that performs well, then when it does, add in the remaining logic.

Add `EXPLAIN` before the query to see the query plan.

I will add that if it is using a lot of CPU, then it is likely that you are missing an index, and time is spent scanning memory pages (table scan).  Ensure that all join columns and all columns in where clauses are indexed appropriately.

Comment: hi thanks man you guided me to right path
there was some errors in your query i fixed those and now my query is 10 time more optimise.

Comment: SELECT id,player_id,name,firebase_token,highscore 
, @num := if(@points = `highscore`, @num, @num + @c) as rank
, @c := if(@points = `highscore`, @c+1, 1) as dummy
, @points := (`highscore`) as dummy2 
from (
SELECT Match_History.id,`player_id`,`name`,`firebase_token`,max(`highscore`) as highscore,`fb_pic_url`,`profile_pic`
FROM Match_History
LEFT JOIN players ON Match_History.player_id = players.id where contest_id=1501
GROUP by player_id  
ORDER BY `highscore`  DESC) t